# Office Word 2016: How to by default use two spaces between two sentences?

Tags: microsoft-word

My supervisor likes to use two spaces between two sentences. I wonder if I could achieve this in the Office Word 2016?

He thinks one space should be used within a sentence, while two spaces should be used between two sentences so as to see the break clearer.

But I have already written a lot using only one space. I do not want to do it one by one.

Comment: I'd ask him if he still thinks it's the 1940's. That's about when it started falling from the style guides. Most ratified guides these days specify single spacing. The double-space between sentences death-knell was the advent of kerned type on computers. Send him to have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing

Answer (score 4):

To fix the existing text, do a simple Find/Replace (x denotes a blank - StackExchange would collapse real blanks) `".x"` with `".xx"`, and then Find/Replace `".xxx"` with `".xx"`: first replace one blank with two, and then three blanks with two - the latter recovers the places where you already had two blanks.

Comment: Nice answer to a stylistically weird requirement ;)

Comment: You can do this with a single find and replace as well:  If you do a wildcard find for (. )([! ]) and set the replace to be \1 \2, you are looking for a full stop followed by a single space followed by any character other than a space, and inserting the extra space in between.